How to Optimize Preprocessing and Post-Processing in DETR-Based Object Detection?
My Question:
How can I reduce the time spent on preprocessing and post-processing?
Background Information
I'm implementing object detection on video frames using DETR. My system processes frames from a 30 FPS, 30-second video (900 frames total), which are read from a Redis queue in batches of 30 and processed on an NVIDIA RTX A4000 GPU. Despite the high-end hardware, I noticed that the GPU is not fully utilized. Here's a breakdown of my pipeline and timing results:
Pipeline Overview

Frames are read from Redis and decoded.
The DetrImageProcessor processes the frames.
The DETR model performs inference.
Post-processing is applied to generate detection results.

Timing Results (Total: 74.38 seconds for 900 frames):
Key Observations:

Post-processing (post_process_object_detection) is the bottleneck, taking 34.13 seconds for all frames.
Input preparation (processor(images=frames, ...)) also takes significant time: 29.30 seconds.
Total detection time (outputs = model(**inputs)) takes 3.06 seconds.

Here’s my batch processing code:
frame_consumer.py:
# Batch processing logic
def process_batch():
    for _ in range(30):
        image_bytes = redis_client.rpop(FRAME_QUEUE, 30)
        imgs = decode_img_list(image_bytes)
        results = model2.process_batch(imgs)

model.py:
import torch
from transformers import DetrImageProcessor, DetrForObjectDetection
from processing_timer import ProcessingTimer
import time

device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
print(f"device: {device}")
processor = DetrImageProcessor.from_pretrained(
    "facebook/detr-resnet-50", revision="no_timm"
)
model = DetrForObjectDetection.from_pretrained(
    "facebook/detr-resnet-50", revision="no_timm"
).to(device)

model.eval()

def process_batch(frames):
    inputs = processor(images=frames, return_tensors="pt").to(device)
    with torch.no_grad():
        outputs = model(**inputs)
    target_sizes = torch.tensor([frame.shape[:2] for frame in frames]).to(device)
    results = processor.post_process_object_detection(outputs, target_sizes=target_sizes)
    del outputs
    del inputs
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()
    return results

Additional Information:

GPU: NVIDIA RTX A4000 16GB
Processor: Intel Core i9-13900K
CUDA version: 12.4
Python version: 3.12
PyTorch version: 2.5.1+cu124

What I've Tried:

Profiling individual pipeline steps to identify bottlenecks.
Clearing GPU cache after each batch.


previous iteration with a few comments: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79211285/how-to-optimize-preprocessing-and-post-processing-in-detr-based-object-detection
